# c# hiding method calls like .net reactor

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I'm trying to write my own c# obfuscator with Mono.cecil library. I want to write a tool like .net reactor but, I really can't understand how does "Hide method calls" property of .net reactor work. Can anyone explain it or suggest me any article about this topic? I searched on the internet but couldn't find any useful stuff.

[image]

I searched on the internet but couldn't find any useful stuff.

Comment: Did you try and decompile a reactor-obfuscated binary? What happens if you try to resolve one of the wrapper methods (eg. `vmWjm8iZat45JQudMW.GfOtPN6gJ`)?

Comment: yeah I tried it but, reactor makes code extremly difficult to read. So, I really couldn't understand anything :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you can't understand how an obfuscation tool obfuscates by studying the result, you basically have no chance of writing one yourself (at least not one that obfuscates correctly, without breaking the code). The basic idea is simple: take a call of the form `A.B()` and transform it into `X.Y(p)`, with `X.Y` a new method that uses the parameter `p` to resolve things back to `A.B()`. Exactly how this is done and what's in `p` is the meat and potatoes of the obfuscation; multiple approaches are possible.

Comment: thanks for answer but, Can you suggest me some articles?